# How do I pass arguments in Django REST framework modelviews?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here is my views for DRF API

```
class CityEventsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        queryset = CityEvents.objects.filter(city=kwargs.get('city_name'))
        serializer_class = CityEventsSerializer
```

URL:

```
router.register(r'cityevents/(?P<city_name>[\w\-]+)/$', CityEventsViewSet, base_name='cityevents')
```

I am not able to access the views function. It is not able to resolve the URL.

Comment: the `queryset` and `serializer_class` are not intended to provide in the `__init__()` method

Comment: request.QUERY_DICT.get('city_name', None)

Comment: to clarify, they should be directly set in the class attributes : https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#modelviewset

Comment: even if i put inside the def get() function. it doesn't work. Do you have any working example of views and url with arguments

Comment: @AnandThati Can you add `CityEvents` model?

Comment: Do you intend to return valid queryset, based upon request parameter city_name?

Answer (score 1):

```
kwargs['city_name']
```

if I understand well what you mean

Answer (score 0):

The url kwargs can be accessed in anywhere in the viewset as it is an instance attribute of the viewset. As a result, you don't need to do that filtering in `__init__()` but in the `get_queryset()` method.
Something like this should suffice:

```
    def get_queryset(self):
        city_name = self.kwargs['city_name']
        queryset = CityEvents.filter(city_name=city_name)
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

This fix worked for me. The retrieve function will receive the arguments passed through the url. and we don't need to add the regex in URL

```
class CityEventsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = CityEvents.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CityEventsSerializer
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        queryset = CityEvents.objects.filter(city=pk)
        return JsonResponse(CityEventsSerializer(queryset,many=True).data,safe=False)
```

URL :

```
router.register(r'cityevents', CityEventsViewSet)
```

Comment: `Serializer` already returns a JSON object, I don't think you need to explicitly use `JsonResponse`. Also, I would suggest using a ListAPIView if you only have get method returning a list of city events.

Comment: I need it in a Json format. Serializer returning in tuples format.